# setCircular for a RoundedBitmapDrawable doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, roundedbitmapdrawable

I'm trying to create a Circular image view by using the following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.user);
RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(mContext.getResources(), bitmap);
drawable.setCircular(true);
```

I saw this example in many tutorials and in Android's developers page:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html

this is the explanation of setCircular function:

public void setCircular (boolean circular)

Sets the image shape to circular.

What am I missing here?

I tried to look at the source of the RoundedBitmapDrawable in Android Studio and indeed there is no setCircular function.
My target API is 22.

Comment: it is v4 support library, then most likely you have an old version

Comment: what do you mean? I need to update my support library?

Comment: just checked the SDK manager and my support library version is 23.1.1

Comment: @AviZana SDK manager shows downloaded versions. The version you actually use is specified in build.gradle file. Check what version do you use and if it is not the latest one - update accordingly

Comment: compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

Comment: you need version 23.0.0 (or newer): `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'`

Comment: you have to import this file 
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory;

Comment: @pskink changing the compile version to 23 solved it, thanks